# Typescript generic callback object strictness

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Im struggling to understand why the following doesnt throw an error

```js
type Callback<T> = () => T

function format<V>(callback: Callback<V>): V {
    return callback()
}

type Test = {foo: string}

format<Test>(() => {
    return {
        foo: 'hello',
        bar: 'dd' // I expect an error to be here as `bar` does not exist on type Test
    }
})

// if I explicitly set the return type in the callback then I get the correct error

format<Test>((): Test => {
    return {
        foo: 'hello',
        bar: 'dd' // this now errors as I have set the return type.
    }
})
```

I cant help but feel this is a duplication?

Is this a `typescript` limitation and is "as expected", or are my `types` incorrect?

Comment: What's the question? If you think this is wrong I'd raise an issue on the GitHub page for typescript. *why the following doesnt throw an error* because the typescript transpiler doesn't `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Why does the callback function in `format` requires to be explicitly set a return type to show the error and why the first case is not showing the error? OP feels like typing `Test` twice should not be required (the later case) when `format` function clearly indicates what the return type is.

Comment: @Liam hey - yeah Ive clarified my question with - is this a expected `typescript` limitiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) is not triggered because `callback` doesn't have explicit type notation. Typescript infers its type as `() => { foo: string; bar: string }` which is assignable to `Callback<Test>`.

Have a look at this example:

```
type Callback<T> = () => T

type Test = { foo: string }

const extendedCallback = () => ({ foo: 'hello', bar: 'bar' }) // inferred as () => { foo: string; bar: string }

const callback: Callback<Test> = extendedCallback // assignment is valid
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYB4AqA+KAXigAoBKIgnAWACg7RIocIBnYIqAbygDMB7fgC4o7AE4BLAHYBzKAF86dNPynsoEAB7AIUgCYQ98JKkydylUjwHCoAcgAWEJPzsAaKKjEi7XuwooAekCoaV4IMTFDKDhWUgpCAmtBEXFpGQBuTzhvUWBJWQUlWhU1DjREFHQMEWMqzFw2YAJiLR19QzrTDChgmNZWCRkpAFtdDgk4gDdECT0gA)

Comment: Thanks for that. Does that mean as long as it extends `Test` it will pass? And therefore I require explicitly setting the return type then?

Comment: Object literals undergo excess property checking only when there's explicit target type.